# hibernate ClassCastException with mvn spring-boot:run

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

when I start the server using the jar:

```
java -jar core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

then everything works fine.

But when i use the maven plugin:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

then i get the following error message:

```
2020-09-28 23:09:46.633 DEBUG 13970 --- [           main] d.j.p.server.core.ServerApplication      : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.6.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.8.RELEASE
2020-09-28 23:09:46.634  INFO 13970 --- [           main] d.j.p.server.core.ServerApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-09-28 23:09:49.120 ERROR 13970 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: 
                                                                                                     Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/SessionRepositoryFilterConfiguration.class]: 
                                                                                                     Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'sessionRepositoryFilterRegistration' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
                                                                                                     Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.JdbcSessionConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcHttpSessionConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setTransactionManager' parameter 0; 
                                                                                                     nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [de/jwt/project/server/core/config/BaseDataSourceConfig.class]: 
                                                                                                     Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager]: 
                                                                                                     Factory method 'baseTransactionManager' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
                                                                                                     Error creating bean with name 'baseEntityManager' defined in class path resource [de/jwt/project/server/core/config/BaseDataSourceConfig.class]: 
                                                                                                     Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: 
                                                                                                     Factory method 'baseEntityManager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType 
                                                                                                     (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
2020-09-28 23:09:49.167  WARN 13970 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-09-28 23:09:49.188 ERROR 13970 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what the cause can be,
i am grateful for every help

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.jwt.project.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Server</name>
    <description>Server</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!--<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-session-bom</artifactId>
                <version>Bean-SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>-->

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Bean-SR3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent -->

        <!-- send email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jwt.project.remoteservice</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.jwt.project.remoteservice</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.imagej/ij -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
            <artifactId>ij</artifactId>
            <version>1.52i</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.agital.project.caritas</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.agital.project.caritas</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wickedsource.docx-stamper</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx-stamper</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**@SpringbootApplication main class**

```
package de.jwt.project.server.core;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.naming.NoPermissionException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import de.jwt.project.database.components.ModelResource;
import de.jwt.project.database.components.Referenz;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Account;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Geschaeftspartner;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.GespeicherteAbfrage;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Instanz;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Instanzwert;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Rolle;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Team;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.Vertrag;
import de.jwt.project.database.tenant.VertragInstanzBez;
import de.jwt.project.database.types.OperationsForQuery;
import de.jwt.project.remoteservice.components.ReferenzHierachy;
import de.jwt.project.server.core.dao.tenant.AccountDao;
import de.jwt.project.server.core.dao.tenant.RolleDao;
import de.jwt.project.server.core.migration.MetadataGenerator;
import de.jwt.project.server.core.multitenant.MultiTenantFilter;
import de.jwt.project.server.core.service.AccountService;
import de.jwt.project.server.core.service.ResourceService;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ServerApplication {

    private static Account login(final ConfigurableApplicationContext context, String username, String password,
            String tenant) {
        final AccountDao accountDao = context.getBean(AccountDao.class);
        final RolleDao rolleDao = context.getBean(RolleDao.class);

        final AccountService accountService = context.getBean(AccountService.class);
        final MetadataGenerator metaGen = context.getBean(MetadataGenerator.class);
        
        Account admin = null;
        try {
            admin = (Account) accountService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (admin == null) {
            admin = new Account();
            admin.setUsername(username);
            admin.setPassword(password);
            Rolle rolle = rolleDao.findByDescription("Administrator");
            if (rolle == null) {
                rolle = new Rolle();
                rolle.setDescription("Administrator");
                rolle = rolleDao.save(rolle);
            }
            Set<Rolle> rollen = new HashSet();
            rollen.add(rolle);
            admin = accountService.save(admin);
            admin.setRoles(rollen);
            admin = accountService.save(admin);
        }

        metaGen.execute(admin, "metadaten_caritas.xml");

        return admin;
    }

    private static void encryptPW(final ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        final BCryptPasswordEncoder enc = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        final AccountDao accountDao = context.getBean(AccountDao.class);
        
        // -------------------------------
        final List<Account> lstAccount = accountDao.findAll();
        for (final Account account : lstAccount) {
            if (!account.isEncrypted()) {
                account.setPassword(enc.encode(account.getPassword()));
                account.setEncrypted(true);
                accountDao.save(account);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Throwable {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream inputStream = ServerApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties")) {
            properties.load(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String username = properties.getProperty("backenduser");
        String pw = properties.getProperty("backenduserpassword");
        Account account = login(context, username, pw, "carritas_db");
        
        // Verschlüssele Passwörter im Klartext
        encryptPW(context);
        //createAuskunftverlangen(context, account);

    }

    private static void createAuskunftverlangen(ConfigurableApplicationContext context, Account account) {
        final ResourceService ressourceService = context.getBean(ResourceService.class);
        try {
            GespeicherteAbfrage abfrage = (GespeicherteAbfrage) ressourceService
                    .getByDescription(GespeicherteAbfrage.class, "Auskunftsverlangen");
            if (abfrage != null) {
                return;
            }
            
            ReferenzHierachy hierachy = new ReferenzHierachy(Instanzwert.class, true);
            hierachy.addJoin(Instanz.class, "instanz", "id", "instanz", null);
            hierachy.addJoin(VertragInstanzBez.class, "id", "instanz", "vib", "instanz");
            hierachy.addJoin(Vertrag.class, "vertrag", "id", "vertrag", "vib");
                        
            hierachy.addCondition(hierachy.createFilter(Referenz.class, "geschaeftspartner", OperationsForQuery.EQUALS,
                    new Geschaeftspartner().toReferenz(), "instanz"));
            
            hierachy.addAdditionalField(String.class, "wert", null, "gespeicherter Wert");
            hierachy.addAdditionalField(ModelResource.class, "referenz", null, "gespeicherte Referenz");
            hierachy.addAdditionalField(String.class, "vertragsnummer", "vertrag", "Vertragsnummer");
            hierachy.addAdditionalField(String.class, "description", "vertrag", "Vertrag");
            
            Team team = new Team(account);
            abfrage = new GespeicherteAbfrage();
            abfrage.setBesitzer(team.toReferenz());
            abfrage.setDescription("Auskunftsverlangen");
            abfrage.setAbfrage(hierachy.serialize());
            abfrage = (GespeicherteAbfrage) ressourceService.save(abfrage);
        } catch (IOException | NoPermissionException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

        final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(someFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/api/auth/login/*");
        registration.setName("MultiTenantFilter");
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    }

    public Filter someFilter() {
        return new MultiTenantFilter();
    }
}
```

**BaseDataSourceConfig**:

```
package de.jwt.project.server.core.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "de.jwt.project.server.core.dao.base", 
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "baseEntityManager", 
    transactionManagerRef = "baseTransactionManager"
)
public class BaseDataSourceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean baseEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("persistence.base");
        em.setDataSource(baseDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("de.jwt.project.database.base", "de.jwt.project.database.components");
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.afterPropertiesSet();
        return em;
    }
    
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource baseDataSource() {
        DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder.create()              
                .build();
        return ds;
    }
 
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager baseTransactionManager() {
  
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager
          = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
          baseEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

The image shows the point where the exception is thrown.
The cast exception is thrown in the AttributeConverterDefinition.resolveType() method.
[image: Exception]

And her the code from the ReferenzConverter.class.
This is the class which cause the cast exception.

```
package de.jwt.project.database.components;

import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(
    autoApply = true
)
public class ReferenzConverter<T extends ModelResource> implements AttributeConverter<Referenz<T>, UUID> {
    public ReferenzConverter() {
    }

    public UUID convertToDatabaseColumn(Referenz<T> attribute) {
        return attribute == null ? null : attribute.getId();
    }

    public Referenz<T> convertToEntityAttribute(UUID dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Referenz ref = new Referenz(dbData);
            return ref;
        }
    }
}
```

.....................................................

Comment: How is your jar packaged?

Comment: Can you post your maven configuration?

Comment: @tmarwen are the pom and properties enough or you need some additional informations?

Comment: Could you add your `BaseDataSourceConfig` configuration class? You can remove the properties as well as they are irrelevant to your issue.

Comment: @tmarwen i added the config and some debug infos from the exception. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: can you post pom.xml? also the @SpringBootApplication main class?

Comment: @gtiwari333 here you go.